# Swift - Opening another app in else statement

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, url-scheme

I would like to open Uber app from my app, when score number will be higher than 25.  Here is my code:

```
        scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"


        if score <= 5
        { promilLabel.text = "Trzezwy"
        }
        else if score <= 10{
            promilLabel.text = "Wesoly"
        }
        else if score <= 15{
            promilLabel.text = "Pijany"
        }
        else if score <= 25{
             promilLabel.text = "Napierdolony"
        }
        else{
            promilLabel.text = "Wytrzezwialka"
        }
    }
```

I found sth like this, but how to add it to else statement?:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "app://") where UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
} else if let itunesUrl = NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/itunes-link-to-app") where UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(itunesUrl) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(itunesUrl)      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function like:

```
func callUrl(){
if let url = NSURL(string: "app://") where UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
} else if let itunesUrl = NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/itunes-link-to-app") where UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(itunesUrl) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(itunesUrl)      
}
}
```

and call this function in else.

```
else{
        promilLabel.text = "Wytrzezwialka"
        self.callUrl()
}
```

Comment: Everything works fine, but instead of opening uber app it goes straight to appstore. Any ideas?

Comment: The way i have structured above is fine, try changing your URL. And I answered what you asked. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! :))) Still cant open app installed on device. It redirects me straight to itunesUrl

Comment: @PawelZet Kindly accept it. If it helps you. All the best (Y)

Answer (score -1):

It works like this:

```
func callUrl(){
          if let url = NSURL(string: "uber://"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url as URL) {
              UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
          } else if let itunesUrl = NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/itunes-link-to-app"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(itunesUrl as URL) {
              UIApplication.shared.openURL(itunesUrl as URL)
            }
            }
```

and in else statemen just added:

```
self.callUrl()
```

Comment: You copied my answered and posted here.

Comment: It is not straight your answer. I've changed it a little bit thats why i posted it here. And it does not fully works.

Comment: Your question says “how can I add to else statement?”

Comment: Yes, and you helped with that. Thank you. Thats correct. But I've changed code a little bit to work properly, thats why i posted which one worked for me. Now I know how to put this function in else statement. One thing i dont it is why it is not opening uber app straightly, but with link in else if. Once again thank you for your help